# Telethon InviteToChannelRequest

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Hello I tried to add users to my Channel with telethon InviteToChannelRequest.
My code:

```
    channel = InputPeerChannel(id, hash)
    user = InputPeerUser(id, hash)
    client(InviteToChannelRequest(channel=channel, users=[user]))
```

I don't get an error but it doesn't work.
I tried with nearly all possible types of channel and users, but nothing seems to work.
Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `AddChatUserRequest` [method](https://lonamiwebs.github.io/Telethon/methods/messages/add_chat_user.html):

```
client(AddChatUserRequest(
    chat_id=123456789,
    user_id=example,
    fwd_limit=10
))
```

**Note: you need to be an channel admin**